# Example of not converging Picard iteration

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $h(t,s)$ and $K(t,\sigma)$ be two polynomials, and $x_{0}(t,s)$ a continuous function (can be a polynomial) defined on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$. Fixed $t\in [0,1]$, consider the "Picard iteration"

$$
x_{n}(t,s):=h(t,s)+\int_{0}^{t}K(t,\sigma)x_{n-1}(t,\sigma)d\sigma , 
$$
for every $n\geq 1$. So, each $x_{n}(t,s)$ can be considered as a continuous function in the variable $s$.

I am looking for $h(t,s), K(t,s), x_{0}(t,s)$ as above such that:

(1) For each $t\in [0,1]$, the sequence $(x_{n}(t,\cdot))_{n\geq 1}$ remains bounded. That is, $|x(t,s)|\leq M$ for every $n\geq 1$, $s\in[0,1]$ and some $M>0$.

(2) There is $t\in [0,1]$ such taht the sequence $(x_{n}(t,\cdot))_{n\geq 1}$ does not have any converging subsequence. That is, by defining for each $n\geq 1$ the function $y_{n}(s):=x_{n}(t,s)$, for every $s\in[0,1]$, the sequence $(y_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ (in the space of the continuous functions, endowed the supremum norm) is not precompact.

Many thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: is it the multiplication of $K(t, \sigma)$ and $x_{n-1}(t, \sigma)$ under the integral? if no, what does the comma mean?

Comment: Thanks for your observation. The comma has been deleted.

Comment: Does $t$ play any role here? could we simplify the question to functions $x_n(s),h(s),K(\sigma)$?

Comment: The letter t can be considered as a constant in the definition of $x_{n}$, $h$ and $K$, but conditions (1) need to be verified for some $t\in [0,1]$ and (2) for every t in [0,1]. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have tried with h and K as in the statement and $x_{0}=0$ (the identically null function), but the resulting sequence converges.

Comment: It might be helpful if you can explain why you think such a thing exists - my first instinct was that it probably doesn't. Consider that a polynomial defined on a compact interval is Lipschitz. I suspect a solution, if it exists, can by found by following the proof of the Peano existence theorem, which establishes that the sequence of functions is equicontinuous, then try to violate equicontinuity.

Comment: I suppose the upper bound on the integral should be $s$, not $t$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such functions do not exist. Since $h$, $K$, and $\frac{\partial h}{\partial s}$ are polynomials, they are all bounded on $[0,1]^2$ by some common constant $C$. Furthermore, by (1) there exists $M_t$ such that $|x_n(t,s)| \le M_t$ for all $t,s \in [0,1]$ and all $n$. Then the fundamental theorem of calculus gives
$$
|y_n'(s)| = \left|\frac{\partial x_n}{\partial s}(t,s)\right| = \left|\frac{\partial h}{\partial s}(t,s) + K(t,s) x_{n-1}(t,s)\right| \le C(1+M_t),
$$
so that $(y_n)$ has uniformly bounded derivatives, implying that $(y_n)$ is equicontinuous. Furthermore, $|y_n(0)| = |h(t,0)| \le C$ is uniformly bounded, so by Arzela-Ascoli the sequence $(y_n)$ has a uniformly convergent subsequence.

Comment: Thanks Lukas Geyer!! Your answer seems very nice, but I have a doubt: $|y_{n}(0)|=|h(t,0)|$ ? Moreover, in such case, is then the sequence $y_{n}$ uniformly bounded?

Comment: @user123043: I am assuming that the upper bound of the integral is $s$, not $t$, so that it is actually like Picard iteration. In that case the integral is $0$ for $s=0$, so you only end up with $y_n(0)=h(t,0)$. Uniform boundedness at a point is enough to apply Arzela-Ascoli, but if you really want, you can also just estimate $|y_n|$ by the bounds on $h$, $K$, and $x_{n-1}$ and get a uniform bound for all $s$.

Comment: Thanks Lukas, but the upper bound of the integral is "t".So, the Fundamental Th of Calculus may be not well applied in this casse, no?

Comment: @user123043: If the upper bound is actually $t$, then this has nothing to do with Picard iteration. Furthermore, the integral does not even depend on $s$ then, so you can call it $C_{t,n}$ and write $y_n(s)=h(t,s)+C_{t,n}$, which means that the modulus of continuity of each $y_n$ is the same as that of $h(t,\cdot)$. By your assumption (1) the sequence is uniformly bounded, and by Arzela-Ascoli you again get a convergent subsequence.